# Apache fails to start with new ssl certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, ssl-certificate, httpd

I'm running RHEL 6.4 and my trusted certificate has expired recently, so I decided to renew it. I've obtained a new certificate from StartSSL.
After downloading and putting the certificate file on the server, I specified the new certificate in `httpd.d/ssl.conf`.

```
/sbin/service httpd configtest
```

says `Syntax OK`,
but

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

causes `[FAILED]` result with no error message. Where can I find the actual reason?

UPDATE:

```
[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.mywebsite.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

these lines were found in error_log of particular viruatal host.

(www.mywebsite.com is substitution of real domain for conspiracy reason of course)

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/httpd/error_log`?

Comment: Are you using the correct key, the key you used to create the CSR that you send to startssl? If you are using your old key and new cert apache does fail to start.

Comment: only "[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down" in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: what if I used old key for producing csr? is it wrong way? is it necessary to genereate new private key for csr each time?

Comment: No using the old key is fine. If that is what you did then its OK.

Comment: Also check the error log for this particular virtual host.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've discovered new data for research in virtual host log. (the question is upated)

Comment: This should be merged with http://serverfault.com/q/459275/87017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch` means that the private key you have specified does not match the public key in the certificate you have specified.

Make sure that you are referencing the correct key and certificate files in your configuration.

`RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) 'www.mywebsite.com' does NOT match server name!?` may be a sign that it is the wrong certificate that has been specified.